# Can you set Axis to use HTTP/1.0 programmatically?

Tags: apache-axis

We're trying to use Axis2 to call a web service that cannot use HTTP/1.1 (default transport protocol in Axis2). Is it possible to programmatically set Axis2 to use HTTP/1.0? I know that this can be done with a configuration file, but in our case API use would be much better solution.

Here's some code that we're using:

```
ServiceClient client = new ServiceClient();
Options opts = new Options();
opts.setTo(new EndpointReference(endpointAddress));
client.setOptions(opts);
```

I tried to figure out if I could somehow use the Options object to set transport protocol, but didn't yet succeed. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I was a bit trigger-happy with sending the question... I just find out from the Axis documentation that you can set the HTTP version with the following code:

```
options.setProperty(org.apache.axis2.context.MessageContextConstants.HTTP_PROTOCOL_VERSION,
org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPConstants.HEADER_PROTOCOL_10);
```

and as the MessageContextConstants.HTTP_PROTOCOL_VERSION seems to be deprecated, I can use the following:

```
opts.setProperty(HTTPConstants.HTTP_PROTOCOL_VERSION, HTTPConstants.HEADER_PROTOCOL_10);
```